# Mediacodec, decode byte packet from server and render it on surface

Tags: android, bytebuffer, android-mediacodec, blockingqueue

I have some issues with MediaCode.

I have 3 components; Decoder, Downloader and Render. And Simple `FragmentStreamVideo` that initialize the 'SurfaceView' and the 'Downloader'.

The other components like the Render and Decoder are initialized in the SurfaceView. Then, a syncronize is done between the Decoder and the Dowloader, implemented by `BlockingQueue<String>` queue where `String = Filename` (*Each frame has its file*).

Another syncronize between Decode and Render is done by the standard ByteBuffer as stated in documentation.

Find below my piece of code. Would be very grateful if you can help.

**SurfaceView**

```
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private Render drawThread;
private Decoder decoder;
BlockingQueue<String> queue;
Context mContext;
public MySurfaceView(Context context,BlockingQueue<String> queue){
    super(context);
    this.queue = queue;
    mContext = context;
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
}
public void setRunning(boolean value){
    drawThread.setRunning(value);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    //drawThread = new Render(getHolder().getSurface(),300,300);
    drawThread = new Render(getHolder().getSurface(),352,288);
    decoder = new Decoder(drawThread,queue,mContext);
    decoder.start();
    drawThread.setRunning(true);
    drawThread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    // завершаем работу потока
    drawThread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry) {
        try {
            drawThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // если не получилось, то будем пытаться еще и еще
        }
    }

}
```

**Render**

```
public class Render extends Thread{
private boolean mConfigured = false;
private long mTimeoutUs;
private MediaCodec mDecoder;
volatile boolean mRunning = false;
byte[] header_sps = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 103, 100, 0, 40, -84, 52, -59, 1, -32, 17, 31, 120, 11, 80, 16, 16, 31, 0, 0, 3, 3, -23, 0, 0, -22, 96, -108 };
byte[] header_pps = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 104, -18, 60, -128 };

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public Render(Surface surface, int width, int height){
    mTimeoutUs = 1000l;
    //возможны проблемы с инициализацией
    ByteBuffer csd0 = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
    csd0.put((byte) MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG);

    try {
        configure(surface,width,height,csd0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

synchronized void configure(Surface surface, int width, int height,
                            ByteBuffer csd0) throws IOException {
    if (mConfigured) { // просто флаг, чтобы знать, что декодер готов
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    // создаем видео формат
    MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", width, height);
    // передаем наш csd-0
    //format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", csd0);
    //format.setByteBuffer("csd-0",ByteBuffer.wrap(header_sps));
    format.setByteBuffer("csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap(header_pps));
    // создаем декодер
    mDecoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
    // конфигурируем декодер
    mDecoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
    mDecoder.start();
    mConfigured = true;
}
void decodeSample(byte[] data, int offset, int size, long presentationTimeUs, int flags) {
    if (mConfigured) {
        // вызов блокирующий
        int index = mDecoder.dequeueInputBuffer(mTimeoutUs);
        if (index >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer buffer = mDecoder.getInputBuffers()[index];
            buffer.clear(); // обязательно сбросить позицию и размер буфера
            buffer.put(data, offset, size);
            // сообщаем системе о доступности буфера данных
            mDecoder.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, size, presentationTimeUs, flags);
        }
    }
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo(); // переиспользуем BufferInfo
        long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (mRunning) {
            if (mConfigured) { // если кодек готов
                int index = mDecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, mTimeoutUs);
                if (index >= 0) { // буфер с индексом index доступен
                    // info.size > 0: если буфер не нулевого размера, то рендерим на Surface
                    while (info.presentationTimeUs / 1000 > System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs) {
                        try {
                            sleep(10);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    mDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(index, info.size > 0);
                    // заканчиваем работу декодера если достигнут конец потока данных
                    if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) == MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) {
                        mRunning = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // просто спим, т.к. кодек не готов
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        // освобождение ресурсов
        release();
    }
}
public void setRunning(boolean value){
    mRunning = value;
}
void release() {
    if (mConfigured) {
        mDecoder.stop();
        mDecoder.release();
    }
}
```

**Decoder**

```
public class Render extends Thread{
private boolean mConfigured = false;
private long mTimeoutUs;
private MediaCodec mDecoder;
volatile boolean mRunning = false;
byte[] header_sps = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 103, 100, 0, 40, -84, 52, -59, 1, -32, 17, 31, 120, 11, 80, 16, 16, 31, 0, 0, 3, 3, -23, 0, 0, -22, 96, -108 };
byte[] header_pps = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 104, -18, 60, -128 };

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public Render(Surface surface, int width, int height){
    mTimeoutUs = 1000l;
    //возможны проблемы с инициализацией
    ByteBuffer csd0 = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
    csd0.put((byte) MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG);

    try {
        configure(surface,width,height,csd0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

synchronized void configure(Surface surface, int width, int height,
                            ByteBuffer csd0) throws IOException {
    if (mConfigured) { // просто флаг, чтобы знать, что декодер готов
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    // создаем видео формат
    MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", width, height);
    // передаем наш csd-0
    //format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", csd0);
    //format.setByteBuffer("csd-0",ByteBuffer.wrap(header_sps));
    format.setByteBuffer("csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap(header_pps));
    // создаем декодер
    mDecoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
    // конфигурируем декодер
    mDecoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
    mDecoder.start();
    mConfigured = true;
}
void decodeSample(byte[] data, int offset, int size, long presentationTimeUs, int flags) {
    if (mConfigured) {
        // вызов блокирующий
        int index = mDecoder.dequeueInputBuffer(mTimeoutUs);
        if (index >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer buffer = mDecoder.getInputBuffers()[index];
            buffer.clear(); // обязательно сбросить позицию и размер буфера
            buffer.put(data, offset, size);
            // сообщаем системе о доступности буфера данных
            mDecoder.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, size, presentationTimeUs, flags);
        }
    }
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo(); // переиспользуем BufferInfo
        long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (mRunning) {
            if (mConfigured) { // если кодек готов
                int index = mDecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, mTimeoutUs);
                if (index >= 0) { // буфер с индексом index доступен
                    // info.size > 0: если буфер не нулевого размера, то рендерим на Surface
                    while (info.presentationTimeUs / 1000 > System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs) {
                        try {
                            sleep(10);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    mDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(index, info.size > 0);
                    // заканчиваем работу декодера если достигнут конец потока данных
                    if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) == MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) {
                        mRunning = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // просто спим, т.к. кодек не готов
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        // освобождение ресурсов
        release();
    }
}
public void setRunning(boolean value){
    mRunning = value;
}
void release() {
    if (mConfigured) {
        mDecoder.stop();
        mDecoder.release();
    }
}
}
```

Downloader (Not full because more function Work)
in readFramePacket function I'm save file and put it on queue it's work fine.

```
public class Downloader extends Thread{
private final byte COMMAND_ONE = (byte)0x01;
private final byte COMMAND_TEN = (byte)0x10;

private final byte MAIN_TYPE_STREAM =(byte) 0x00;
private final byte SUPPORT_TYPE_STREAM =(byte) 0x01;
private final byte CONTROL_CODE_DISCONNECT =(byte) 0x00;
private final byte CONTROL_CODE_CONNECT =(byte) 0x01;

private final byte DELIMITER = (byte)':';
private final int FIX_PACKET_HEAD_SIZE = 5;
private final int SECOND_HEAD_FIX_SIZE = 4;
private final int FIX_DELIMITER_SIZE = 1;
private static final int HEAD_OF_PACKET = -1;
private static final int SECOND_HEAD_OF_PACKET = 0;
private static final int DATA_PACKET = 1;
private static final int PACKETS_END = -2;
private static final int LAST_PACKET = 8;
private static final int COMMAND_INDEX = 0;
private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT_LENGTH = 5000;
private String log;
private String pass;
String host;
int portNumber;
BlockingQueue<String> queue;
Socket socket;
Context mContext;
OutputStream out;
int cameraID;
int value = 0;

volatile boolean mRunning = false;


public Downloader(Server server,BlockingQueue<String> queue,int cameraID,Context context){
    log = server.getLogin();
    pass = server.getPassword();
    host = server.getIP();
    portNumber = Integer.parseInt(server.getPort());
    this.queue = queue;
    mRunning = true;
    this.cameraID = cameraID;
    mContext = context;
}
public void stopStreaming(){
    mRunning = false;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(host, portNumber);
        socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(sockaddr, SOCKET_TIMEOUT_LENGTH);
        //socket.setSoTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT_LENGTH);

        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        out = socket.getOutputStream();
        byte[] command = createAuthenticationPacket(log, pass);
        out.write(command);
        readAuthPacket(inputStream);
        byte[] connectCommand = packetToConnectDisconnectCamera(cameraID,SUPPORT_TYPE_STREAM,CONTROL_CODE_CONNECT);
        out.write(connectCommand);
        initializeVideoStream(inputStream);
        readFramePacket(inputStream);

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give more details on the place of the problem. What's working as not expected?

Comment: I think problem in configure function(Render) or on decodeSample, because no one frame not Render on Surface. Because when i debug project In thread Render
int index = mDecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, mTimeoutUs); always return -1;

Comment: @Marlon what do u think?

Comment: do you send correct sps,pps headers to decoder?

Comment: @marlon Yes, i take it from the server. How i should initialise first ByteBuffer flag BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG, if i take frame like byte array. pls contact me for more operative dialog  a23sokolov@gmail.com if u can

Comment: @Marlon what do u think?